# How to disable reloading tableview when scrolling in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to disable reloading table view when scrolling. Now, my app when user scroll the uitableview, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has been recalled. How can I disable it when srcolling? Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d,%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *FileNameLabel;
    UILabel *UploadTimeLabel;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        CFileNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 130, 30)];
            UploadTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 130, 25)];


        FileNameLabel.tag = 1000;
        FileNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
        FileNameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        FileNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        //  FileNameLabel.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: FileNameLabel];
        [FileNameLabel release];


        UploadTimeLabel.tag = 2000;
        UploadTimeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UploadTimeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
        UploadTimeLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        // UploadTimeLabel.text = [UploadTimeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: UploadTimeLabel];
        [UploadTimeLabel release];


    }

    if( [OriginalArray count] > 0)
    {
        UILabel *fileNameLbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
        //fileNameLbl.text =[temp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        fileNameLbl.text =[[OriginalArray valueForKey:@"FILENAME"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *uploadlbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2000];
        uploadlbl.text =[[OriginalArray valueForKey:@"UPLOADTIME"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    _tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot block the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` from calling when scrolling the tableview. If something need not happen every time, You may keep it in if condition.

```
 if (cell == nil)
    {
        //Functionality goes here when it not needed to happen every time.
    }
```

Comment: This is correct, whenever a cell is scrolled into view it will come from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not implement the method `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourID"];` or `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier:nil];`

It will prevent the table view from reusing the cell. But its not a good idea if your tableview is going to contain large number of cell. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to avoid being reloaded, maybe you could play with your data source, so that it appears as the data doesn't change. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: can you provide some examples

Answer (score 1):

use dequecellforrowatindex method to avoid cell reloading.

Comment: Please, either you create a comment or provide some source code for your suggested function.